# Integrating Simple Code Into Complex Code

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, function, uilabel

I have a very simple code that I cannot "fit" into my more complex project due to me being a complete novice at coding.

The objective of this code is to generate a random string/element from an array, without repeat, until the entire array is exhausted.

I've pasted the code below that achieves the functionality that I'm looking for.

My issue is: I cannot seem to find a way to integrate the functioning code into my much larger project that has entirely separate folders for structs, protocols, etc.

My question is:

Is there a way to take the struct I've created below, and integrate the working code from my other project to achieve this?

I've been working on the issue for days now to no avail.

Here is the current "Struct" I have in the complex project:

```
import UIKit
struct Test {

    var text : String

    init(text: String) {
        self.text = text
    }
}
```

Here is the working function that achieves the end result I want in my other project:

```
    var array = ["Lindsey", "Fun", "Beach", "Dog",]
    @IBOutlet var testing: UILabel!
    @IBAction func wow(_ sender: Any) {
        let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(array.count)))

        testing.text = (array[randomIndex])

        array.remove(at: randomIndex)
    }
}
```

I've received a number of different errors, too many to even begin to list. At this point, I cannot figure this out.

Comment: It's completely unclear what you are asking. What is the point of your `Test` struct? What does it have do with the other code that you posted? Show the code you have actually tried so far and explain what problems you are having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the only reason you want to pull in the code from your other project then there's a far easier option:

to get a random enrty in your array

```
let random = array.randomElement()
```

or to get a random index

```
let randomIndex = Int.random(in: 0 ..< array.count)
```

If that's not what you mean, then you need to further clarify your question.

Comment: OK @CodeMan123, think we're getting there.  However test doesn't have an array property.  Are you wanting text to have an array of strings and return one of those, or just to use Test's existing `text` property and return a letter from that (the implementation will be different due to the different way arrays and strings are indexed).